# How to save a pdf file in Http url in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I will be generating one pdf file where i have a location like http://www.example.com/ContextName/DefaultFolder..

where i need to save files in Default folder could you please help in in this.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly provide more detail.

Comment: from server side you can not specify location where the browser will save the file.